# extracting sub strings from a line

Tags: regex, perl, tcl

I want to match two sub strings from a few lines in a file.
e.g. I've these lines here:

```
                DU.DUALGN.D3_D5H0TOD4B_RS1DQ.ELC.L2

                DU.DUALGN.D3_D5H0TOD4B_RS2DQ.ELC.L2 

                EC.DU.DUAB0.D0_OPBQ.ELC.L2
```

I've millions of line like above and I want to extract lines only  containing DUALGN and ELC.L2

Please help me how to write a regular expression for this.

Comment: Does the `DUALGN` always precede the `ELC.L2` if both are present? And does the `ELC.L2` always come at the end of the line? These will help a lot with making the RE more optimal.

Comment: yes DUALGN always preceded the ELC.L2 but ELC.L2 may not be always at the end of the line

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -ne 'print if /DUALGN/ and /ELC\.L2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Tcl is more verbose than Perl here:

```
tclsh << 'END'
set fh [open "filename" r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    if {[regexp {DUALGN} $line] && [regexp {ELC\.L2} $line]} {
        puts $line
    }
}
END
```

Since we're looking for fixed strings, we don't need to invoke the regex engine. This will probably be faster:

```
    if { [string first "DUALGN" $line] > -1 && 
         [string first "ELC.L2" $line] > -1
    } {
        puts $line
    }
```

---

Using a single regex:

This version uses [lookaheads](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M25) which were introduced in Tcl 8.1 if I recall.

```
^(?=.*DUALGN)(?=.*ELC\.L2)
```

This means: starting at the beginning of the string, look ahead to find "DUALGN" and look ahead to find "ELC.L2". You would use this same regex in Perl.

If your Tcl version can't handle that for some reason, you can do this

```
(?:DUALGN.*ELC\.L2)|(?:ELC\.L2.*DUALGN)
```

This means: find "DUALGN" followed eventually by "ELC.L2" or find "ELC.L2" followed eventually by "DUALGN".

---

Because Donal made me ;) -- some timings:

```
% set line "DU.DUALGN.D3_D5H0TOD4B_RS1DQ.ELC.L2"
DU.DUALGN.D3_D5H0TOD4B_RS1DQ.ELC.L2
% time {string match *DUALGN* $line; string match *ELC.L2* $line} 1000000
1.122276 microseconds per iteration
% time {string first DUALGN $line; string first ELC.L2 $line} 1000000
1.0179 microseconds per iteration
% time {regexp {^(?=.*DUALGN)(?=.*ELC\.L2)} $line} 1000000
12.840028 microseconds per iteration
% time {regexp {(?:DUALGN.*ELC\.L2)|(?:ELC\.L2.*DUALGN)} $line} 1000000
12.770246 microseconds per iteration
% time {regexp DUALGN $line; regexp ELC\\.L2 $line} 1000000
1.140218 microseconds per iteration
```

Conclusion: choosing to use one regex, you happen to have picked the slowest implementation.

Comment: thanks ...I am more interested in tcl answer. You are using here or "|" operation between DUALGN and ELC\.L2 but my condition will be true when I'll get both of them in a single line. Could you please provide some more insight in that.

Comment: thanks Glenn!! appreciate your help. But I've another tricky scenario on top of this. I can use only regexp here to extract the lines and ( can't use any other options) that is also with only one regexp ( not two ). Actually I've written a C code which has regexp command built in. I am parsing a tcl file as an interface here and this tcl file has just these names ( DUALGN, ELC\.L2) which I want to extract. these name are going to map with an another text file which has millions lines in it. So I am curious to know how to  extract them using a single regexp here

Comment: `string match *DUALGN* $line` might be faster still; `time` it and find out for sure (and Tcl *might* internally optimise very simple `regexp` calls to `string match` internally anyway…)

Comment: @DonalFellows, not quite, and yes it appears so.